# Android SDK Server listening on a given interface

Tags: java, android, sockets, network-programming

I have developed a TCP server with Android SDK code using the `ServerSocket` class.

I want this server to work only on the cellular network (3G/4G) and not on the wifi network. To be more precise I want it to listen only connections from `rmnet0` interface, not from the `wlan0` one.

Any idea?

Comment: "I want this server to work only on the cellular network (3G/4G) and not on the wifi network" -- um, from a security standpoint, that's not a wise move. In the best-case scenario, a server on the cellular network is limited to some subset of the subscribers on the same network (due to NAT). In the worst-case scenario, the carrier gives out public IP addresses, and the server is visible to the entire Internet. How big is your legal defense fund?

Comment: This device is working with a special SIM card that has a static IP on a VPN. So it is totally secure.